# Using .bat or .lnk file to automate cmd and do user input

Tags: batch-file, cmd, automation, shortcut

I would like to create a .bat or .lnk file (preferably a .lnk file) to automate the following sequence in cmd for me:

```
>runas /user:5CG95082M0\School "C:\Users\School\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe""
Enter the password for 5CG95082M0\School: [my user password is an input here]
Attempting to start C:\Users\School\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart Teams.exe as user "5CG95082M0\School" ...
```

here is my question: how do I make the file to automatically input my user password when it is prompted I should do so?

Notice that the command is `runas` and that it waits for a user input. I've read that the use of `echo` to do that has been removed. As a proof (or is it?), note this when ran on `cmd`:

```
C:\Users\7329934>echo [my password] | runas /user:5CG95082M0\School "C:\Users\School\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart "Teams.exe""
Enter the password for 5CG95082M0\School:
Attempting to start C:\Users\School\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart Teams.exe as user "5CG95082M0\School" ...
RUNAS ERROR: Unable to run - C:\Users\School\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Teams\Update.exe --processStart Teams.exe
1326: The user name or password is incorrect.
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Automatic input of passwords, especially in plain text, is a _very_ bad security practice. You should _not_ do this.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Thanks! however, now out of curiosity, how will I be able to do that?

Comment: If the program in question takes its input from the standard input stream, you _may_ be able to redirect input from a file (foo < infile), or pipe it in from another command (echo bar | foo). If it doesn't, you can't. Since this appears to be MS Teams, which does _not_ take input from the standard input stream (it's a Windows application, not a console application), you're going to be out of luck.

Comment: @Jeff, Ilay: `echo bar | foo` pipes the string `bar<space> to the application `foo`. Use `echo bar|foo` or more safe `(echo bar) | foo`. But as already said, this does not work with every application.